# How to parse this info into individual items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have scraped the following info from a web page using the following scrapy spider. How can I turn this info into individual items, that is one item should consist of name, size, link, extension, month, and year.

Here is the code of the spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class MapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'map'
    allowed_domains = ['map.gob.do']

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = [
            'https://map.gob.do/transparencia/recursos-humanos/nominas-de-empleados/']
        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse,)

    def parse(self, response):
        panes = response.xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div/section/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/ul/li')
        tables = response.xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div/section/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div')
        for pane in panes:
            Id = pane.css('::attr(href)').get(default='')
            Year = pane.css('::text').get(default='')
            yield{
                'year': Year,
                'id': Id
            }
        for d,table in enumerate(tables,1):
            yearId = table.css('.tab-pane ::attr(id)').get(default='')
            months = table.css('#'+ yearId + '.tab-pane .vr-tabs-nav-link ::text').getall()
            monthsIds = table.css('#'+ yearId + '.tab-pane .vr-tabs-nav-link ::attr(href)').getall()
            print(f'|||YEAR \' {d} \' INFO |||')
            yield{
                'yearId': yearId,
                'months': months,
                'monthsIds': monthsIds,
            }
            for c,monthId in enumerate(monthsIds,1):
                itemNames = table.css(monthId  + ' tr .wpfd_downloadlink ::attr(title)').getall()
                itemsLinks = table.css(monthId + ' tr.file .wpfd_downloadlink ::attr(href)').getall()
                itemsSizes = table.css(monthId + ' tr.file .file_size::text').getall()
                itemsExt = table.css(monthId + ' tr.file .wpfd_downloadlink > span > span ::attr(class)').getall()
                print(f'|||MONTH \' {c} \' INFO |||')
                yield {
                    'monthId': monthId,
                    'itemsNames': itemNames,
                    'itemsSizes': itemsSizes, 
                    'itemsLinks': itemsLinks,
                    'itemsExt': itemsExt
                }

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MapSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: you may need another `for`-loop and `zip()` to group values for individual items

Comment: or you should first get all `tr` and use `for`-loop to work with every `tr` separatelly. And then you should get values for individual row. It can have also advantag - if one of row have missing data then your version doesn't catch it but it moves value from next row in place of missing value - and you get wrong results. Working with every `tr` separatelly you can catch missing element in row and put some default value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did it with Lukas method sub indexing as the selectors are giving me the info I'm looking for, but I took your tip to substitute missing values with default ones. Now I'm having problems importing my item into the spider. It's giving me an ModuleNotFoundError should I ask this here or should I open another question.

Comment: better create new question on new page because you have to show FULL error message. OR better first check this error in Google - maybe someone already resolved this problem - importat is what module it can't find. Probably you have file in wrong folder. Scrapy expect spiders and models in special folders in project.

Comment: I have looked around in google and found people with similar error but none of the solutions posted have worked for me. I'll try a little more before I open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your `table.css(...).getall()` returns multiple values, which you all pack into the `yield`. The advantage of yield as opposed to return is that you can also choose your chunksizes.

Replace the general yield with the more specific one you want. e.g.

```
for i in range(min(map(len, [itemNames, itemsLinks, itemsSizes, itemsExt]))):
    yield {
         'monthId': monthId,
         'itemsNames': itemNames[i],
         'itemsSizes': itemsSizes[i], 
         'itemsLinks': itemsLinks[i],
         'itemsExt': itemsExt[i]
          }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was very helpful. Now I'm having a problem importing my Item to the spider. it's giving me an ModuleNotFoundError. Should I open a new question for that?